# Searching for a song with Zenity in Bash

Tags: bash, id3, zenity

I've got a problem with my BASH project. It's a simple songs ID3 search app. There is a bug that when I find my song, the `$SONG` doesn't concatenate with `$FOUND`. However it works until I print them below the separator line. What is going wrong?

```
TITLE=""
FOUND=""

while [ 1 -eq 1 ]; do
    OUTPUT=$(zenity --forms --title="Search" --text="Search by ID3" --separator="," --add-entry="Song title")
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        TITLE=`echo $OUTPUT | cut -d "," -f 1`
        find . -name "*.mp3" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' SONG
        do
            echo "$SONG"
            if [ "$TITLE" ]; then
                if id3info "$SONG" | grep "=== TIT2" | grep -q "$TITLE"; then
                    FOUND="${FOUND}${SONG}"
                    echo "Found song: $SONG"
                    echo "All: $FOUND"
                fi
            fi
        done
        echo "================================="
        echo "$FOUND"
        echo "$FOUND" | zenity --text-info --height 500 --width 500 --title "Songs"
    else
        exit
    fi
done
```